# Can we pass the textbox values(autocomplete) to controller without using jquery ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Initially i have used this controller for searching the text once after clicking the search button.

but now i need to make it as a autocomplete textbox. this is the view page

**View:cshtml**

The textbox value needs to be passed to controller.

```
   <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.TextBox("search", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                </div>
              </div>
            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
       </div>
```

**IndexContoller:**

Can i able to call this without using jquery ajax?

```
  public ActionResult Search(string searchText)
        {
            var category = from s in db.Table
                           select s;
            category = category.Where(x => x.CategoryName.Contains(searchText));
            category = category.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryName);
            int pageSize = 6;
            int pageNumber = 1;

            return View(category.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only if you wrap the textbox in a form and submit the form

Comment: `Html.BeginForm` with a `<input type="submit" />` button should solve this. However, autocomplete requires callback process (without reloading the entire page) which usually handled on client-side by `jQuery.ajax` function.

Comment: i would like to use this textbox as a autocomplete one. @StephenMuecke

Comment: Yes I know, but to do that you need javascript (and ajax unless you included all options in the view), so why not use ajax to submit the value?

Comment: since i had an edit,del,update option with mny parameters in tat so oly..@StephenMuecke

Comment: I have no idea what your last comment means

Comment: sorry..i have so many divs along with bootstrap classes, so i have decided to check whether there is any option in to do that so. @StephenMuecke